# Выгрузка массива изображений из firebase в ячейку

Tags: swift, swift3, firebase, firebase-database

Всем привет. Может кто подсказать как выгрузить разное кол-во фотографий из firebase в одну ячейку с названием?
Я могу выгрузить по одной фотографии в одну ячейку из firebase, но выгрузить несколько фотографий в одну ячейку понять не могу как это сделать. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И Database я предполагаю должен выглядеть так и мне соответственно надо выгрузить все image, количество картинок разное, где то 2, где 5 и тд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код как делаете. В чем именно загвоздка?

Comment: Загвоздка в выгрузке разного количества изображений, как например с моего скриншота из вопроса, я хочу выгрузить в Дубаи image и image2 чтобы в collectionView отобразилось 2 картинки, а в Лондоне image...image5 и чтобы в collectionView отобразилось 5 картинок. Но у меня сейчас получается выгружать количество картинок равное количеству названий. Надеюсь не затруднит посмотреть код с github https://github.com/denikaev/test2
Буду очень признателен за помощь в решении моей проблемы

Comment: новая ссылка - https://github.com/denikaev/test2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите в `prepareForReuse()` все кроме обнулений, он вызывается когда Вы проскроллите до ячеек, которые до этого не были видны. Т.е. сразу Вы не получите информацию для видимых ячеек.

Дальше по Вашему вопросу. В `loadNameAddress()` полностью разберите ответ, не дергайте в каждой ячейке базу. Затем передавайте в ячейки просто массив с ссылками photos:

```
struct NameAddress {
    ...
    var photos = [String]()
    ...
    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        ...
        if let photosDict = snapshotValue["Фото"] as? [String: String] {
            for (_, keyValue) in photosDict.keys.enumerated() {
                if let photo = photosDict[keyValue] {
                    photos.append(photo)
                }
            }
            ...
```

В результате будут такие массивы:

```
["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city1.jpg?alt=media&token=c442fd8f-4cc4-4e30-8242-975aaf5427dc", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city1.jpg?alt=media&token=c442fd8f-4cc4-4e30-8242-975aaf5427dc"]
```

С ними уже и работайте в UICollectionView ячейки

Comment: Спасибо. 
Пока не добрался до компьютера чтобы проверить, но я правильно понимаю что если мне нужно будет добавить например третью фотографию для первого name, то мне это нужно будет добавлять и в firebase и в массив photos?

Comment: Наверно немного не то что мне нужно, но за prepareForReuse спасибо. Собственно у меня идея такая, что я буду добавлять новые название, адреса и изображения и они в режиме онлайн будут появляться в приложении. Я подумал как можно было бы по другому это реализовать, но не могу понять как добраться до узла "Фото" в каждом из новых названий. Не подскажите как добраться до узла?

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в ячейку горизонтальный UICollectionView и передавать ему необходимые данные.

Comment: UICollectionView я добавил и передаю туда данные в одном экземпляре, но не могу понять как передать массив/словарь (не знаю как лучше передавать) данных как у меня указано в FB, image1, image2 и тд